# Padding left or right also creates space at the bottom

Tags: php, html, css

Not exactly an issue since I can easily achieve the desired effects using a margin, but just curious: why does specifying the padding left or right for a div also create a space at the bottom of the div?
[image: officelocation]

```
<div class="col-md-12 row" style="margin:0px;padding:0px"> 

                                            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left:0px">
                                                <img src="/images/1.jpg">
                                            </div>

                                             <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left:10px">
                                                <img src="/images/2.jpg">
                                            </div>

                                             <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-right:0px">
                                                <img src="/images/3.jpg">
                                            </div>


</div>
```

I expected this code to line up the three images perfectly. But as you can see in the picture: the middle image, having padding-left:10px is also creating some padding at the bottom despite it specifying 0px. I resolved the issue by using margin in the img tag and avoiding padding, but it made me curious: why would padding-left create space at the bottom?

Comment: _"why would padding-left create space at the bottom?"_ - probably because the image is set to scale with the available width - which just got _reduced_ due to your additional sideways padding - and so, since it resizes proportionally, keeping its aspect ratio, the height also gets reduced.

Comment: `<div class="col-md-12 row"` - that makes rather little sense, and might lead to unexpected results. An element can hardly "be", fulfill the function of, a row and a column at the same time.

Comment: Agree with @CBroe and following that wouldn't use three columns inside a row help achieve that? Or if using only HTML CSS then using display inline-block can also help achieve that.

Comment: @CBroe yes, that makes sense. Thanks. if you want, you can post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: also thanks for pointing out the column. I just discovered that removing col-md-12 has no adverse effects. you learn something every day............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why would padding-left create space at the bottom?

Probably because the image is set to scale with the available width - which just got reduced due to your additional sideways padding. And so, since it resizes proportionally, keeping its aspect ratio, the height also gets reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Add a fixed width and height for the pictures and use object-fit: cover like this:

   ```
   <img src="/images/3.jpg" width="200" height="80" style="object-fit: cover">
   ```
2. Do the same thing but with the images as a background and use background-size:cover

Keep in mind that this will crop your picture to fit the size.

Comment: as a future reference for other readers, simply not using the padding attribute for div, and using the margin attribute in the <img> tag to achieve required space between the three pictures work just as well as a workaround.